# React-Router not receiving props if it's the same path, but different param?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a path `/player/:id/`

If I navigate from say `/player/12` to `/player/13` it will error out, for example: `cannot find foo of undefined`. However if I navigate from a different path such as `/heroes/100` to `/player/12` it will load fine.

My suspicion is that when I link from the same route, but different param, the new page is not invoking my useEffect or setState hooks.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here, but I can't figure it out. If my suspicion is correct, does anyone know how i can force my component to use my UseEffect and UseState hooks before loading the page when going from the same route, but different params?

The params are correct, it's displaying the correct id in the url bar. If i refresh the page it'll load fine, but if i click the link it'll error out `Cannot read property 'hero_id' of undefined`

Thank you

Context:

```
playedAgainst.map(player => <Link key={Math.random()} to=
{"/players/" + props.invertedPlayers[player]}> <span> {player} </span></Link>
```

Each iteration creates a new Player name, with a Link. When i click on that link it says all "cannot read property hero_id of undefined". However, when i refresh the page it loads fine. I'm 100% sure the link path is correct. I used the exact same code in a different component that leads to the Player component.

(The Math.random is definitely sloppy, i'll remove that!)

```
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Search players={this.state.players} />
            <GameList players={this.state.players} data={this.state.games} />
            <Footer />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/players/:id">
            <Player players={this.state.players} invertedPlayers = {_.invert(this.state.players)} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/heroes/:id">
            <Heroes players={this.state.players} invertedPlayers = {_.invert(this.state.players)} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        </Router>
```

EDIT -

I added the following hook to my Players component.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect fired');
}, [])
```

When i go from 1 id to another (same route, different param) the useEffect hook is not firing.

Seems like i need to get my useEffect to fire when following the same routes with different ids.

Accessing my Params via useParams():

```
let { id } = useParams();
  const [player, setPlayerData] = useState({ data: null, image: null });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response1 = await axios(`/api/players/${id}`);
      const response2 = await axios(`/api/saveImage/${id}`)
      setPlayerData({ data: response1.data, image: response2.data });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

EDIT 2 -

Added to ID to useEffect, but useEffect is still not rerunning for some reason:

```
let { id } = useParams();
  const [player, setPlayerData] = useState({ data: null, image: null });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response1 = await axios(`/api/players/${id}`);
      const response2 = await axios(`/api/saveImage/${id}`)
      setPlayerData({ data: response1.data, image: response2.data });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);
```

EDIT 3 -

More context, hopefully this helps:

As soon as the component loads it pulls data from the API to load within the component. This works fine. When i click a ling to the same route, but different param, the useEffect hook to pull data doesn't run.

```
const Player = (props) => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const [player, setPlayerData] = useState({ data: null, image: null });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response1 = await axios(`/api/players/${id}`);
      const response2 = await axios(`/api/saveImage/${id}`)
      setPlayerData({ data: response1.data, image: response2.data });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('count changed');
}, [])

  console.log('test')
    return (
        <div className="historyContainer">
...............

{player.data && player.data.map((game, i) => {
    const heroIdOfPlayer = game.players.find(p => p.account_id === +id).hero_id; 
    const teamOfPro = game.players.find(p => p.hero_id === +heroIdOfPlayer).team;
```

The part under the '.......' is where `Cannot read property 'hero_id' of undefined` is coming from, which only happens when clicking through the link.

A few lines further down:

```
{playedAgainst ?
            playedAgainst.map(player => <Link key={Math.random()} to={"/players/" + props.invertedPlayers[player]}><span> {player} </span></Link>)
            : ""}
```

This is how each link is generated. The path is correct. if i follow the path it'll say `Cannot read property 'hero_id' of undefined`, but when i refresh the page it will load fine.

EDIT - 4

Adding my App component in case this helps:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: [],
      players: {},
    };
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname)
    this.loadGames();
    this.loadPlayers();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.loadGames();
    }, 5000);

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.loadGames();
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  async loadGames() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/games');
    const myJson = await response.json();
    const sortedJson = myJson.sort((a, b) =>
      a.spectators > b.spectators ? -1 : 1,
    );
    this.setState({ games: sortedJson });
  }

  async loadPlayers() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/playersList');
    const myJson = await response.json();
    this.setState({ players: myJson });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Search players={this.state.players} />
            <GameList players={this.state.players} data={this.state.games} />
            <Footer />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/players/:id">
            <Player players={this.state.players} invertedPlayers = {_.invert(this.state.players)} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/heroes/:id">
            <Heroes players={this.state.players} invertedPlayers = {_.invert(this.state.players)} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: console.log(this.props.params);
after /player/12 to /player/13

Comment: No need for this, since its a functional component with hooks right? Also, don't i need to do `let { id } = useParams()` and then console.log(id) ?

The params are correct, it's displaying the correct id in the url bar. If i refresh the page it'll load fine, but if i click the link it'll error out `Cannot read property 'hero_id' of undefined`

Comment: Changing of a param should trigger a re-render. You shouldn't even need to watch the param in `useEffect` or anything. Maybe some relevant code might help, since in general: prop changes = re-render.

Comment: @Jayce444 added some relevant code. I think you're right about the re-render trigger. I think the issue might be that the page is trying to load before the useEffect and setState hooks have finished running. I might be wrong though.

Comment: How are you accessing the route params? Please include the component code accessing the route props. NOTE: route props aren't automatically passed to children when rendered like this, they need to either be decorated with the `withRouter` HOC or use the use `useParams` hook.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm accessing my params via the useParams hook. The url is correct when i click the link, so surely that means I'm accessing the params correctly?

Comment: @DrewReese Also I added a console.log(id) before my return statement and when i follow a link it returns the correct id, but errors out afterwards because useEffect and useState are not invoking.

Comment: @Jav You need to add `id` to the effect's dependency array so when it changes the effect reruns.

Comment: @DrewReese I just did this and it didnt seem to change anything. The useEffect hook is still not rerunning.

Comment: @Jav Please include all relevant code, all places using that effect hook. Each component needs to access the params and needs to trigger the effect correctly in order to function correctly. From the sounds of it we need to see the `Heroes` component.

Comment: @DrewReese I've added numerous detailed edits. The heroes component is not being used at all here. the "heroes_id" is a property within the API call from useEffect, which isn't running.

Comment: Are you sure you are "unpacking" your response data correctly? `useEffect` with empty dependency runs **only once**, on mount, so your count logging won't keep printing. What of your `const teamOfPro = game.players.find(p => ...` have you debugged, i.e. what are the values of `p`? Clearly it is undefined when attempting to dereference the `hero_id` property. Is all this code part of your `Player` component? I'm starting to agree with @James comment to you in his answer.

Comment: @DrewReese Everything is undefined after I follow the link. `useEffect` is not running when i click the link. I'm fairly sure this is the problem. When I click on the link, `useEffect` is not running again, even when I put `id` in the `useEffect` array

Comment: @DrewReese This is probably a misunderstanding on my part, but when I remove the array from `useEffect` and then I click the links, nothing happens. The link doesnt do anything. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: @DrewReese Added my app component code in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your `useEffect` hook, pass the prop that changes as a dependency i.e.

```
useEffect(..., [id])
```

This will ensure `useEffect` runs everytime `id` changes, the problem at the minute is you pass `[]` which means `useEffect` will only run once, when the component is first mounted.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't change anything. The effect hook is still not rerunning for some reason, even though the id does change upon clicking on a link.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hero_id' of undefined` 
`The above error occurred in the <Player> component`

Comment: @Jav that error is completely unrelated to whether `useEffect` is being called or not though, that suggests to me more of an issue with either the data you receive back from the server (is there a property missing that shouldn't be?). You should verify now with the change that the API is now firing correctly when you switch URL and then debug your app to find out why you get the above error (you don't provide enough code for anyone to diagnose that problem I'm afraid).

Comment: I have a useEffect that just logs 'count changed' inside the Player component. When going to a different param, with the same route I am not seeing the 'count changed' log. This must mean useEffect is not firing when I follow the link. If i follow the link from a different component it will load fine. Adding more relevant code now.
It's saying hero_id of undefined because the useEffect hook didnt run, so there is no hero_id property since no data was fetched from the useEffect hook.

Comment: I've added numerous detailed edits, hoping it helps.

Comment: Is there maybe something else we can do to the `useEffect` hook to make it fire when following the link? Right now its not firing when clicking the link, so "hero_id" will always be undefined since it comes from the `fetch` of the `useEffect`

Comment: This is probably a misunderstanding on my part, but when I remove the array from `useEffect` and then I click the links, nothing happens. The link doesnt do anything. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: @Jav your 3rd edit shows two `useEffect` calls and the second with the same empty dependencies as before (so again, I would only ever expect this to fire once). When you remove the dependency array, this is the equivalent to `[]` therefore it will again only fire once. Using the `id` parameter is the correct approach here, if this is _definitely_ not refiring I'd invite you to create a reproducible example on CodePen I could look at for you.

Comment: Okay, will do. I tried adding [id] to both useEffects but none of them fired. It’ll take me a while to do the CodePen but I’ll let you know once it’s up. Thank you.